# Vertical Resource View: custom HTML resources and time slot clicks

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Researching https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view for work

It seems the `columnHeaderHtml` callback does not work for this view.
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/429
Is this still the case? Any way around this?

I also need the ability to click a timeslot.  Eg. clicking the 10 AM row to create an event at 10 AM.  Does this functionality exist? I can't seem to find any callbacks that seem to work.

My codepen so far:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OKyvGZ?editors=0010

EDIT: @ADyson pointed out that `columnHeaderHtml` only works for date headers, not `resource` headers as is the case here.

Comment: The various `columnHeader` settngs only affect the part of the column header which shows the date. Since you're using a 1-day view, the date part of the column header is hidden, and you can only see the resource names, which aren't affected by those settings.

Comment: P.S. that github issue applies to fullCalendar v3 as far as I can see, so won't be directly relevant to the new v4, which is a total re-write. Not being involved in the fullCalendar project myself, I've no idea if there's an open issue about it in v4, you'd have to check the bug and feature request lists on GitHub.

Comment: As for clicking to choose a timeslot, yes the `select` callback is what you need. This will give you a callback providing you with info such as the range of time which was selected (the user can drag to select a longer period if they wish). You can then use that info however you wish - e.g. add an event directly to the calendar, or save the data to your server, or pop up a modal dialog to capture more details about the intended event (e.g. title etc), or some combination of all 3 - it's up to you. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback

Comment: @ADyson thanks a lot for your response.  the `select` callback doesnt ever fire in this view.  did you manage to make it work in the codepen? Seems to me it only works in the non-scheduler views.

Comment: As per the docs, did you set "selectable" to be true? Did you load the interaction plugin? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectable . P.S. There is also a demo codepen linked from the documentation page, which you can copy from! The behaviour is no different in the scheduler vs non-scheduler views.

Comment: Here's a simple working version: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PMPdjx

Comment: @ADyson thanks so much! super helpful. working great.